# Dart pub build: consistency between dart version and compiled js version

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-polymer

I have a Polymer Dart app, in its development, it goes through these two stages:

Stage 1: It works (feature complete and builds OK), but there is no automatic test. (So to guarantee it behaves like what it suppose to behave, I have to manually click some button, type some text in some input fields, to see it behaves correctly.)

Stage 2: I added some test code to the app, use the unittest package to test the app works correctly. The test is against the uncompiled dart code, runs in Dartium, before `pub build`. Then I added a transformer, `lib/transformer.dart`, so that, when `pub build`, my transformer will remove all test-related code in the app, so Polymer, dart2js and other transformers will see exactly the same code they see in Stage 1, except in stage 1, there is no `lib/transformer.dart`.

My questions are:

A. (for stage 1) Should I worry about the consistency between dart version and compiled js version? i.e., can I safely assume that, if my code works correctly in dart version, it will work correctly in js version?

B. Suppose that my transformer does exactly what it suppose to do, which is, remove all newly added, test related codes, (except the transformer itself, of course), suppose also that, the js version of my app already works correctly in stage 1, will the js version of stage 2 also works correctly?

Note: Why do I run the tests in dart version instead of js version? Because I don't know how to it without introducing test codes into js version, i.e., I don't want the js version to contains test code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A: Yes you should worry. 
Working with that Dart code on the client side is mostly for faster development. In the end you have to ensure the built application runs correctly. 
Usually they work the same but there is no guarantee at all. There are a lot subtle and not so subtle differences (timing, browser differences, ...)

B: doesn't apply because of A I guess.

When you put your unit test code in `your_package/test` you don't need to worry about test code in production. This code is only built to JS if you explicitly do (`pub build test`), not by default (`pub build`) .
Your production code in `your_package/lib`, `your_package/web`, `your_package/bin` should **not** contain any  test code.
If it does you're probably doing something wrong.

You should build your tests to JavaScript and test your app with every browser in every version you target.

Comment: Does dart guarantee that two `pub build` on the same code will produce the same js?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't think this is guaranteed. It will guarantee semantic equivalent code. It might be possible that the used minified names differ from one build to the other. For example if things are done in parallel and the timing differs between two runs but I don't know if this is really the case. I remember somewhere mentioned that they aim to use the same minified names even when the code was changed, but can't of course can't guarantee it.

Comment: If I understand it right, the common way to do polymer dart unit testing is this: you write a `<my-elem>`, then you write a `.html` and a `.dart` that uses `<my-elem>`, put these two files under `my_package/test/`, repeat this for all custom elements, then `pub build test` to see if they work correctly.

Comment: ... What I am doing is, use `unittest`, but not really use it to do unit testing, but test on the whole application, more like an automation tool - click this button for me, input 'foo' to that `<input>`, this kind of thing. The benefit of this is, I don't have to maintain many test `.html` (entry points for custom elements), and if I changed something, the entire app is tested, in case that I forget change Foo will affect Bar? Any disadvantages you can see in my method?

Comment: Reply for the second comment: semantic equivalent code is good enough.

Comment: I usually use an `<app-element>` which wraps my entire Polymer application. This way when you test `<app-element>` you test the entire application. You still should have no test code in `lib`, `bin`, or `web`.

Comment: I had this thought, dev the app without test, when it's feature complete, write a `test.dart`, `dart2js test.dart -o test.js`, open `test.js`, copy its contents, launch the js version of the app, open "Dev Tools>Console", paste `test.js`'s contents into it.

Comment: Why would you use `dart2js` instead of `pub build`? If you create your test with an HTML entry point you can just run `pub build test` and run the test like any web application or use `pub serve` and run it with Dartium, Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, ... without explicitely compiling.

Comment: "You still should have no test code in lib, bin, or web"?  Even if I use a transformer to remove the test code so that other transformers would see the same code as if there are no test codes? (I guess other transformers doesn't care about my transformer)

Comment: I can't see the advantage in comparsion to test code in `test` directory. Mixing production code with test code is usually not a good pattern.

Comment: why `dart2js`: If you use a different entry point, `test.html`, to test `<app-elem>`, even if it passes all tests, the real production code, build from another entry point `index.html`, is still untested, (I am being a little paranoid here). To overcome this problem, we don't write test code as part of the package, we write it in js, and it more like an automation tool than a unit test, when the js is pasted into dev tools, it starts too run, which will click this, click that, this kind of thing. But I don't like js, so I write it in dart, compile it to js, hence `dart2js`, not `pub`.

Comment: YMMV but in my opinion I would try to improve efficiency for developers writing tests instead of thinking about and coping with such mostly theoretical issues. I would expect that in an app there are areas where you get more return for your effort. Another issue I see is that it's probably very hard to automate (CI) this way, which I consider very important.

Comment: CI is hard, but not impossible, it will need a real browser and some way to talk to the browser, like WebDriver. (Thanks for your time, you answered almost all my dart questions :)

Comment: BTW, is there a documentation of the format of the output of dart2js, what I am trying to know is, if I copy the output of dart2js to a dart app's console, will it cause conflict, since both of them use `main()`.

Comment: I have no knowledge about this. Maybe building to JS without minification makes it easier to investigate it yourself. Otherwise I think you should create a new question because I doubt anyone will read all the comments above and find this quesiton ;-)